# Сужение диапазона генерации случайных чисел

Tags: python

Ниже представлен код, создающий 4 случайных предмета. Каждый предмет может обладать определенной редкостью: *редкий*, *супер-редкий*, *эпический*, *мистический*, *легендарный* (расположены в порядке увеличения редкости).

Требуется добиться следующего поведения: редкость первого предмета выбирается случайно без ограничений, а каждого следующего - случайно, но не меньше предыдущего.

```py
import random

rare = 0.5
superrare = 0.28
epic = 0.15
mythic = 0.05
legendary = 0.02
q = 'rare'
a = 'superrare'
b = 'epic'
c = 'mythic'
d = 'legendary'
t = 0
while t != 4:
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        print("rare")
        q += '1'
        t += 1
        if q == 'rare1':
            rare = 0.0
    elif random.random() < 0.28:
        print(a)
        a += '1'
        t += 1
        if a == 'superrare1' or q == 'rare':
            superrare -= 0.28
            rare -= 0.5
    elif random.random() < 0.15:
        print(b)
        b += '1'
        t += 1
        if b == 'epic1' or a == 'superrare' or q == 'rare':
            epic -= 0.15
            superrare -= 0.28
            rare = 0.5
    elif random.random() < 0.05:
        print(c)
        c += '1'
        t += 1
        if c == 'mythic1' or b == 'epic' or a == 'superrare' or q == 'rare':
            mythic -= 0.05
            epic -= 0.15
            superrare -= 0.28
            rare -= 0.5
    elif random.random() < 0.02:
        print(d)
        t += 1
        if d == 'legendary':
            d = '0'
```

**Внимание**: текст вопроса является вольной интерпретацией задачи, изначально изложенной так:

> "Как сделать выпадение только 4 редкости не хочу чтобы редкость понижалась допустим если epic не хочу что бы было rare"

Возможны "неточности перевода".

Comment: Вопрос непонятно написан. Советую переписать в теле вопроса со знаками препинания. Что сразу бросается в глаза - random.random() надо сгенерить один раз, а не генерить заново при каждой проверке. Присвойте результат генерации переменной и с ней сравнивайте

Comment: не понял ваше предложение, я бы хотел чтобы генерировалось 4 редкости и чтобы они были в повышении, а не ухудшении например: rare, rare, rare, superrare, а не rare, epic, rare, rare, типо если выпала редкость больше предыдущей, то что бы она больше не появлялась

Comment: Попробуйте для начала в тексте вопроса подробно описать что требуется. У вас пока текст вопроса в заголовке, в комментарии. В общем везде кроме того места где это нужно. И не очень понятно описан сам вопрос.

Comment: Сгенерируйте сразу четыре предмета и отсортируйте их.по возрастанию редкости и скажите пользователю, что они выпали в таком порядке.

Answer (score 3):

**UPD**

Стало интересно решить эту задачу двумя способами:

1. **Важен результат** - надо получить четыре случайных предмета с заданными вероятностными весами, в порядке неуменьшения. Способ решения не важен.
2. **Важен способ** - эти предметы надо получать строго *друг за другом*, по очереди.

**1. Способ**

Берем список парных кортежей, в котором записаны пары **вероятность выпадения:название редкости**. С помощью `random.choices()` собираем список из четырех редкостей, учитывая веса вероятностей. Сортируем по вероятностям. Печатаем.

```
import random

rarity = [
    (0.02, 'legendary'),
    (0.05, 'mythic'),
    (0.15, 'epic'),
    (0.28, 'superrare'),
    (0.5, 'rare')
]

print(*[r[1] for r in sorted(random.choices(rarity, weights=[r[0] for r in rarity], k=4), reverse=True)], sep='\n')
```

**2. Способ**

Для начала поменяем веса на кумулятивные. Это избавит нас от **пустых событий** (ни один предмет не выбран).
Находим случайный предмет, соответствующий заданной вероятности, сравнивая сгенерированную вероятность с каждой вероятностью из списка с нижней до верхней. Когда предмет найден делаем два действия - отсекаем бОльшие вероятности, а оставшийся диапазон нормализуем до единицы. И идем на следующую итерацию.

```
import random
import numpy as np

rarity = [
    (0.02, 'legendary'),
    (0.05, 'mythic'),
    (0.15, 'epic'),
    (0.28, 'superrare'),
    (0.5, 'rare')
]

# порог вероятностей, выше него будем все удалять
max_r = 1

# пересчитываем кумулятивную сумму либо с numpy
rarity = [(x, r[1]) for x, r in zip(np.cumsum([i[0] for i in rarity]), rarity)]

# либо без numpy
# rarity = (lambda lst: [(sum(lst[0:i]), rar[1]) for i, rar in enumerate(rarity, 1)])([i[0] for i in rarity])

for _ in range(4):
    rarity = [(x[0] * 1 / max_r, x[1]) for x in rarity if x[0] <= max_r]
    prob = random.random()
    for r in rarity:
        if prob <= r[0]:
            print(r[1])
            max_r = r[0]
            break
```

Comment: Отличная идея! Если в кортежах списка rarity на первое место поставить числа  - `(0.5, 'rare')`, - то можно исключить аргумент `key=lambda x: x[1]`, т.к. при сортировке кортежей по дефолту ключом являются элементы кортежа, начиная с нулевого.

Comment: @АлексейР к моему стыду, этому помешала лень )) я сначала написал кортежи вот так, как они сейчас, а когда дошел до сортировки, понял, что надо было наоборот, но переписывать исходные данные поленился, в надежде, что никто не заметит )) Mea Culpa. Будет мне уроком, что коллеги внимательно следят!) Придется  исправить )

Answer (score 2):

Я не менял ваш код, но добавил вам простенькое и наглядное условие для редкости. Суть в чем, мы сохраняем уже выпавшие редкости и в последующих циклах, нам уже не упадёт редкость ниже той, что уже выпадала:

```
import random

rare = 0.5
superrare = 0.28
epic = 0.15
mythic = 0.05
legendary = 0.02
q = 'rare'
a = 'superrare'
b = 'epic'
c = 'mythic'
d = 'legendary'
t = 0
ra = set()
while t != 4:
    
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        if  "rare" not in ra and\
           "superrare1" not in ra\
            and "epic1" not in ra\
            and "mythic1" not in ra\
            and "legendary" not in ra:
            ra.add("rare")
            print("rare")
        
            q += '1'
            t += 1
            if q == 'rare1':
                rare = 0.0
    elif random.random() < 0.28:
        if  "superrare1" not in ra\
            and "epic1" not in ra\
            and "mythic1" not in ra\
            and "legendary" not in ra:
            ra.add("superrare1")
            print(a)
            a += '1'
            t += 1
            if a == 'superrare1' or q == 'rare':
                superrare -= 0.28
                rare -= 0.5
    elif random.random() < 0.15:
        if  "epic1" not in ra\
            and "mythic1" not in ra\
            and "legendary" not in ra:
            ra.add("epic1")
            print(b)
            b += '1'
            t += 1
            if b == 'epic1' or a == 'superrare' or q == 'rare':
                epic -= 0.15
                superrare -= 0.28
                rare = 0.5
    elif random.random() < 0.05:
        if  "mythic1" not in ra\
            and "legendary" not in ra:
            ra.add("mythic1")
            print(c)
            c += '1'
            t += 1
            if c == 'mythic1' or b == 'epic' or a == 'superrare' or q == 'rare':
                mythic -= 0.05
                epic -= 0.15
                superrare -= 0.28
                rare -= 0.5
    elif random.random() < 0.02:
        if  "legendary" not in  ra:
            ra.add("legendary")
            print(d)
            t += 1
            if d == 'legendary':
                d = '0'
```